# How does "Logout Everywhere" work in PHP?

Tags: php, logout

I just found out that stackoverflow has a link to logout every logged computers.

So..I thought about how to implement same functionality in PHP. I came up with using session_set_save_haldner to control write() method. In write() method, I can make a session file start with user's username. For example, a user john might have session files john_kdkajdkak, and john_29039dla. When John clicks "Logout Everywhere", I can write a code that finds filenames start with "john" then remove them to clear sessions.

are there any other better solutions? How did you implement it if you already made it work?

Comment: The easier way would be to simply not use PHP sessions to track who's logged in. It's relatively easy to implement yourself and would give you a reliable way of doing this. You should back this with database tables or something similar instead of files in the very least.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, it's better to *use* the PHP sessions, but change up the session's cookie name. Roll-your-own sessions has all sorts of security implications and risks, but changing the cookie name is relatively meaningless, and associating that with a user account in a database table is very very easy.

Comment: "has all sorts of security implications and risks" <-- Examples? Hard to qualify this as anything but FUD without them

Comment: The security risks of roll-you-own session management is minimal if you know what you're doing. For many projects the existing PHP session management is good enough - and your time is better spent on other tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a database to persist session data.

Using [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) you can roll your own database storage backend for user sessions - a `sessions` that has a `user_id` foreign key, related to the `users` table. A "logout everywhere" button would trigger  simple `DELETE FROM sessions WHERE user_id = 1234` and invalidate every session for the user.

You can also easily add in additional columns to the `session` table - to store the IP address of the session, for instance, so users can see where other sessions are logged in from.

Use a database for flexibility and performance.

Comment: Is database session faster than file system session??

Comment: Yes - though the main benefit is flexibility and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sites on the same domain, like StackExchange does, then you can do this with PHP.

As Billy already pointed out, the better practice would be to use database storage for this.

In your situation I'd think about using a CAS or similar solution.

But it all boils down to how many different sites you will have with the same account.

Comment: @degiga // My question is not related to multiple sites on the same domain. When you click "logout" on stackoverflow, you will see the following quote. "f you are logged in to Stack Overflow through multiple computers and wish to logout from them all, or you are using a public computer, click below."