# CodeIgniter: how to automatically logged out user from all active sessions after he has changed his password?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My website is made with CodeIgniter 2.1.2. But it has a problem.
Suppose a user has logged into my website using Chrome. Then he has also logged into my website from Mozilla.
When he changes his account password from chrome. He still can browse through the website from mozilla. It's really a big security hole!!
What I want is when the user will change his password he will be automatically logged out from other active sessions too.
How can I do that? :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does "Logout Everywhere" work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061972/how-does-logout-everywhere-work-in-php)

Comment: not actually...